# Regex for a specific string with exact digits

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a regex for the below two strings.

Must start, end and contain only these many digits.

SG2222222C

And

P22222222

THANKS

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. Do you just want to match these two strings or is 2 a placeholder for any digit?

Comment: What language are you using the regex in?

Comment: I am using it in Javascript. 2 is a placeholder where it represents it could be any digits.. So basically the first string should start as SG then exactly 7 digits then at last C.. Similarly second string must start with P then exactly 8 digits

Answer (score 2):

The first one is `SG\d{7}C`: `SG` followed by `\d{7}`, which means "match a number 0-9, seven times" (it does not need to be the same digit), followed by `C`.

On the other hand, if you need the 7 digits to all be the same, you want `SG(\d)\1{6}C`--wrap the first digit in a capturing group (that's the `(\d)`) and then match what was captured by the (first) group 6 times (`\1{6}`).

If you need to match the entire string, you can add `^` and `$` at the start and end, respectively (i.e. `^SG\d{7}C$`).

I'll leave the second one to you. [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is handy for experimenting with regexes.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple. Tested. Works fine**

For SG2222222C:

```
/^[A-Z]{2}\d{7}[A-Z]$/
```

**AND**

For P22222222:

```
/^[A-Z]\d{8}$/
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Problem solved

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please mark the answer as an appropriate answer whenever you find it helpful for your problem. Thanks!